# Unable to enable the input field in react-simple-chatbot NPM module

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I imported this module in my react main component and it seems the input field is in disabled mode. Do we need to explicitly enable it . If so which definition should I use it ?

Answer (score 1):

You should mention `user: true` in steps array object then only it is visible.

```
steps: [
        {
          id: "0",
          message: "Hey, there! How can I help you?",
          trigger: "2"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          user: true,
          trigger: "1"
        }]
```